Баги самодельного сервера на ESP-8266
Завершил написание мини-сервера для записи и хранения текстовых данных. Вот страница проекта (далее речь пойдет про первый релиз):
https://github.com/TimmMuranov/ESP-DISK
Кода немного (полагаю, при должном умении такой проект можно запилить за вечер).
В браузере компа (firefox) всё работает. На телефоне (браузер - ducducgo) столкнулся со сложным (для меня) багом:
При открытии текстовых файлов требуется перезагрузка страницы (для прогрузки пути к файлу). Но перезагрузка удаляет текст, принятый клиентской стороной. Вот краеугольная часть кода (расположена в data/script.js):
buttons.forEach((button) => {
   if (button.getAttribute('id') === 'about'){
     button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      window.location.href = "/a";
      })
    }
    if (button.getAttribute('name') === 'fileButtons') {
      const fileName = button.innerHTML;
      button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
           try {
             const response = await fetch('/f', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                body: JSON.stringify({ fileName })
                     });
            if (!response.ok) {
              console.log('Ошибка: '+response.statusText);
              return;
              }
            const serverResponseText = await response.text(); //принимаем текст с сервера
            inputArea.value = serverResponseText; //вводим текст
            location.reload(); //здесь он сбрасывается(((
           } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error sending data: ', error);
           }
       });
    }
});

В итоге, текст появляется на мгновение и исчезает...
Помогите пожалуйста исправить данную ошибку и (если не сложно) в целом дайте резюме проекту: что добавить, что исправить, а что выпилить (кроме меня и моего детского лепета).
Заранее спасибо :)

Так убери локатион релоад

К сожалению, перезагрузка необходима. Если убрать релоад, то: 1) файлы из одной директории будут переключаться, а имена их в полном пути отображаться не будут. 2) при переходе в другую директорию (точнее при нажатии на кнопку директории) всё равно придется вручную перезагружать страницу, чтобы отправить заново сгенерированную html страницу.

Логика неправильная

А как лучше тогда построить взаимодействие? Задумка в том, чтобы на МК хранились текстовые файлы, а на стороне клиента был простенький интерфейс для редактирования: окно для ввода, кнопки по созданию/удалению файлов/директорий и кнопки-файлы, при нажатии на которые в окне для ввода отобразился бы текст из того файла, на который я нажал. А при редактировании текста в окне он перезаписывался бы на МК (вручную большой кнопкой, как у меня или автоматически)
